# Multiple DB-Connections in Tomcat context.xml?

Tags: java, database, tomcat, galera

I am wondering, if it is possible, to define more than one DB-Connection in the context.xml of a Tomcat (resource-tag).
My problem is, that I have 3 Galeras, which I wanna balance without an explicit loadbalancer. Instead of this, I thought it could be possible to define the 3 connections (different IPs) in the context.xml of my Tomcat. But than I wonder, how the Tomcat would balance this. 
I dont really find something helpful, to answer me that question.

Has anybody an idea?

*EDIT*
I have a JavaEE 7 Application and referenced the mariaDB-Connector in that. (changed the connectors-Lib with the mysql-Connector to mariaDB).

Comment: Wired you don't want do use an explicit load balancer but then you want to write in tomcat a sort of custom load balancer. Is that right?

Comment: (I edited my question) The thing is, that I didnt had a loadbalancer before and thought, that I can handle that with the mariaDB-Connector. I am fairly new to these multiple connections thing and wanna understand, how to handle multiple connections in the Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to write your own load-balancer, you better to leverage Mysql JDBC driver's load balancing support.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-managing-load-balanced-connections.html

Comment: I thank you for your post. I didnt found that for mariadb... I think this line is the answer I needed:
`jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://[host1][:port],[host2][:port][,[host3][:port]]...[/[database]]`